# Visual Studio "Rebuild Solution" order

Tags: visual-studio

I know that rebuilding multiproject solution will clean and then build each project one by one, rather than cleaning all and then building all.

So, the obvious questions will be:

What order does "Rebuild solution" function use for projects?

Is solution's "build order" taken into attention?

Answer (score 2):

As per a similar question here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/34fcc251-b6fe-4878-8274-fa094ae34151/how-do-i-set-the-build-order-of-projects-in-visual-studio-solution?forum=winformssetup

"Visual Studio calculates the build order according to your dependence. If project A depends on project B, Visual Studio will build B priority to A."

This is for both build and rebuild solution.

Comment: Why are you sure this is also for rebuild? Can you provide links to official documentation from Microsoft where your words are confirmed?

Comment: I am sure just based on the rebuild order that follows the same build order based on if you right click on the project solution and select project build order. This order is automatically generated and only can be changed by changing the dependencies. Both build and rebuild use this list. You can verify this by checking the list and then building seeing the order, then rebuilding and seeing that it is the same.

Comment: "seeing" is not enough to be sure.

Comment: As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/building-and-cleaning-projects-and-solutions-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019 if you read the basic information about building/rebuilding they are one in the same other than the simple fact that rebuilding also cleans the solution first.

Comment: Page from the link you provided does not contain information to do such conclusion. The page does not even contain clear information about differences between "build" and "rebuild". They wrote "Choose Rebuild Solution to "clean" the solution and then build all project files and components" but from this sentence you cannot say for sure that "rebuild" uses same mechanic for building solution as "build" did.